# asking about some pseudocode interpretations

Tags: algorithm, pseudocode

I'm learning about writing algorithms in pseudocode. Here are some pseudocodes (informal, self-invented format) that I have written. Some of them seem to have "errors". Can anyone tell me what are the errors? What will actually happen when this code is run?

q1:

```
set finished to false
repeat until finished
    ask 'Enter a value' and wait
    set value to answer
    set cubed to value*value*value
    say join value(join cubed is cubed)
```

q2:

```
set num to 0
set count to 1
forever if num < 100
    set number to count * 9
    say number
    set count to count + 1
```

*For q2 I think the result will either display one number too many or not display any numbers.*
I don't really know about any programming languages (only a little bit of Python) so it would be great if you could explain in general. Thank you and I will really appreciate your help.

Comment: Not sure what `join` is supposed to do. That being said, pseudocode cannot really have "errors" as it is not executed. You cannot actually run pseudocode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To execute pseudocode you need a pseudocomputer, namely yourself. Add line numbers to your code and replace loops with ifs + gotos:

```
1 set finished to false
2 if finished goto 8 # repeat until finished{
3 ask 'Enter a value'and wait
4 set value to answer
5 set cubed to (value*(value*value))
6 say join value(join cubed is cubed)
7 goto 2 # }
8
```

Now go through each step and write down which values your variables take.

```
     finished   value   cubed

1    false
2    false
3    false
4    false      3
5    false      3       27
6    false      3       27
7    false      3       27  # goto 2!
2    false      3       27
3    false      3       27
4    false      2       27
5    false      2       8
6    false      2       8
7    false      2       8   # goto 2!
2    etc...
```

Now the mistake is obvious. Correct it and try again.